# Render a Page object from a template

Tags: lektor

In a Lektor website, I'm facing the following problem:

- I have a flowblock called `facts` with an according template called `facts.html`
- in that template, I search for facts to display as follows: `{% for fact in site.get('/facts').children %}`
- these children have the model `fact` imposed on them and there is a corresponding `fact.html` template that renders them

Now the question is: how do I get to render these child pages inside `facts.html`?

I know this is possible by transforming the `fact.html` template into a macro that can be called from `facts.html`, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant way of achieving the same result.

Is there a `render`-like method available for Page objects?

Comment: After doing some more research, I guess this is not possible, as the Lektor pagination documentation suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not quite follow your setup. You said you have a `.facts` attribute that is of type Flow. However, you perform a query on `/facts` to get its children which suggests that these are sub-pages and not flow blocks. So.. I am not sure what you try to achieve, but:

You can have template files for flow-blocks, you just have to place them in e.g., `templates/blocks/fact.html`. If you do that, you can just print out the flow attribute itself (`<div>{{ this.facts }}</div>`) and all individual flow-blocks will be drawn with the flowblock template.

**EDIT:**

You asked to display another (full) page template into a flow-block type:

```
{% set other = site.get('/projects') %}
{{ site.env.render_template('facts.html', pad=other.pad, this=other)|safe }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! I indeed have both a flowblock and a page called `facts`. I know flowblocks can have templates, and use them as well. I also know how to render blocks from inside a page template. But how do I do the opposite, namely: render pages from inside a block template?

Again, I concluded last year that this is simply not possible, so I went with the macro workaround. But if it is possible, that would be great.

Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, I see. Your initial question stated the opposite, to display a flow-block inside a flow. I've updated my answer to show how you can render arbitrary templates.

Comment: I think I quite clearly stated "Is there a render-like method available for Page objects?", but... whoa! thanks a lot! So it simply does exist! How come I never figured this out myself. I must confess I haven't tried this yet, but I checked the source of Lektor and it's there indeed... Even more... this method seems to have been there since the initial commit... Thanks a lot, lupdidup!